# Add a word to a text area selected from a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select and a button.

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button>Add Selected To Textarea</button>

<textarea rows="5" readonly></textarea>
```

Basically every time I select an option and click the button I need the selected to be added to the textarea in a new line

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addToTextarea() {
  var currentText = $('#textarea').text();
  if(currentText.trim().length == 0) $('#textarea').text($('#cars').val());
  else $('#textarea').text(currentText + '\n' + $('#cars').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button onclick="addToTextarea();">Add Selected To Textarea</button>

<textarea id="textarea" rows="5" readonly></textarea>
```

So you first need to add a click listener to your button calling a javascript function.
In this function you can get the currently selected value from the select element with jquery and add this value to the current text of the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById("text-area-id");


function updateTextArea() {
  const cars = document.getElementById("cars");
  textarea.value += cars.value + "\n"
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button onclick="updateTextArea()">Add Selected To Textarea</button>

<textarea id="text-area-id" rows="5" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: It's almost there but I can only add 1 to the textarea...I need to be able to add multiple one per line or read from an array into the textarea...either would work for me

Comment: This code does exactly what you wanted in your question.

Comment: "*I can only add 1 to the textarea*" (well, click the button again) / *add multiple one per line* / *read from an array* - there is **literally no mention of any of these requirements** in your question.  Did you forget to specify the [mind-reading-cap-required] tag?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addWord(){
  const sWord = document.getElementById("cars").value;
  const oTextarea = document.getElementById("output");
  let sTextareaValue = oTextarea.value;
  if(sTextareaValue.length > 0){
    sTextareaValue = sTextareaValue + "\n";
  }  
  oTextarea.value = sTextareaValue + sWord;
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button onclick="addWord()">Add Selected To Textarea</button>

<textarea rows="5" id="output" readonly></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

As pure jQuery (ie, without a mixture of jQuery and vanilla javascript):

```js
$('button').on('click',() => {
    $('textarea').val( 
        (index,value) => value + $('#cars :selected').text() + "\r\n"
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button>Add Selected To Textarea</button>

<textarea rows="5" readonly></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="btn" onclick="var e = document.getElementById('cars');
        var car = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('txtResult').innerText += car + '\n';">Add Selected To Textarea</button>

<textarea id="txtResult" rows="5" readonly></textarea>
```